# Is there any nonzero infinite sum of polynomials that converges to zero?

Tags: polynomials, convergence-divergence, power-series

Is there any infinite series of polynomials of the form 
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ that converges to zero on the interval $[0,1]$ where at least some $a_i \neq 0$?

Comment: Let $n$ be the least with $a_n\neq 0$. What happens if you divide by $x^n$?

Comment: If so, $a_0$ must be zero (for x=0). Now if you look at the derivative, which is zero cause the function is flat. So you get $a_1=0$. and I guess you can keep going that way.. not sure but it feels to me it is not possible to find such an infinite series of polynomial

Comment: What infinite sequence of polynomials? What is the first polynomial, the second, and so on?

Comment: Do you mean an infinite series of terms each of which is a power series? If so, you could use the Fourier series of a square wave, expressing each sine function by its Taylor series.

Comment: (I'm unclear whether tte *series* has the form you give, or whether the *polynomials* do. And whether the polynomials are terms in the series, or the partial sums of the series.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about a power series $P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^ma_nx^n$ such that $P(x)=0$ for all $x\in [0,1],$ but with $a_n\ne 0$ for some $n,$ the the answer is NO.

First observe that $\infty>M=\sup_{n\ge 0}|a_n|.$ Otherwise $P(1)$ does not exist in $\Bbb R.$

Now suppose $n_0$ is the least $n\ge 0$ such that $a_n\ne 0.$ Then for any $m>n_0 $ and any $x\in (0,1)$ we have $$|\sum_{n=0}^m a_nx^n|=|a_{n_0}x^{n_0}+\sum_{n=n_0+1}^ma_nx^n|\ge$$ $$\ge |a_n|x^{n_0}-\sum_{n=n_0+1}^m|a_n|x^n\ge$$ $$\ge |a_{n_0}|x^{n_0}-\sum_{n=n_0+1}^mMx^n\ge$$ $$\ge |a_{n_0}|x^{n_0}-\sum_{n=n_0+1}^{\infty}Mx^n=$$ $$=|a_{n_0}|x^{n_0}-\frac {Mx^{n_0+1}}{1-x}=$$ $$=x^{n_0}(|a_{n_0}|-\frac {Mx}{1-x}).$$ So for any $x\in (0,1)$ that's small enough that $\frac {Mx}{1-x}\le|a_{n_0}|/2$ we have $|P(x)|\ge |a_{n_0}|x^{n_0}/2>0.$

In general: Let $A<B$ and $C=\max (|A|,|B|).$ If $P(C)$ exists and $P(x)=0$ for infinitely many $x\in [A,B],$ where  $P(x)  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n,$ then every $a_n=0.$

Answer (score 0):

You do not say anything about the meaning of convergence (pointwise, uniform, $\dots$ ?).

Be that as it may, the answer is "yes". Let $p_n(x) = (1/n) x$. Then $p_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a sum $\sum_{n=0}^N a_nx^n$ that converges to 0 for each $x \in [0,1]$ (i.e., $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N a_nx^n = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. So I don't think this addresses the question.

Comment: They might also be calling power series polynomials. It needs clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is whether there exist $a_n$'s  not all $0$ such that $\sum a_nx^{n}=0$ fro all $x \in [0,1]$ the answer is no. The radius of convergence of the series must be at least $1$ and its sum is an analytic function on the open unit disk. The zeros of this function have a limit point so its identically $0$ on the unit disk. This implies that all the coefficients are $0$.